# Cannot get context menu to work in Extjs 4.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

There seems to be lots of documentation about numerous ways of making a **context menu** pop up in Extjs. But nothing works for me.

I have tried :

**rowcontextmenu**

**containercontextmenu**

**gridContextMenu**

I add them to my listeners like so (except gridContextMenu). Am I doing this right?

```
Ext.define('myGrid', {

    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',


    listeners: {
        'rowcontextmenu': function (grid, index, event) {
            alert('xxx')
        },
        containercontextmenu: function (grid, e) {
            alert('xxx');
        }
    },
    gridContextMenu: function (view, rec, node, index, e) {
        alert('xxx');
    },
```

Here is my code in JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8shpjxs2/1/

Is this browser specific? Does some browser behaviour have to be switched off? I am using Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itemcontextmenu`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-event-itemcontextmenu).

```
Ext.define('myGrid', {

    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    listeners: {
        itemcontextmenu: function (view, record, item, i, e, opt) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('xxx');
        }
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/m61arb93/1/

Comment: is there any way of suppressing the browser context menu?

Comment: Sure, just call `e.preventDefault()` (see updated example).